# Несколько параллельных потоков, будут ли проблемы

Tags: java, многопоточность, synchronized

Могут ли возникнуть проблемы при использовании объекта следующего класса в нескольких параллельных потоках? Если да, то как лучше исправить?

```
    public class SomeData {
      private boolean correct;
      private boolean computed;

      public SomeData (/*...*/){
           correct = true;
           computed = false;
      }
      public booolean isCorrect(){
       if (!correct){
          computeCorrectess();
         }
       return correct;
      }

      private synchronized void computeCorrectess(){
         computed = true;
         //some long computation of value correct
         //correct = ...
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

Проблема может быть с методом `isCorrect`

Кейс следующий:
Пусть есть поток А и поток Б, работающие с данным объектом, в обоих потоках одновременно вызывается `isCorrect`, далее:

```
if(!correct){ //correct == false для потока А и для потока Б
//Оба потока попадают сюда, и оба попадут внутрь computeCorrectness, но по очереди.
//Я полагаю что этот метод должен выполниться только в одном из потоков.
    computeCorrectness();
}
```

Для решения данной проблемы рекомендую ознакомится с паттерном [Double checked locking](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_checked_locking)

Comment: Подксажите пожалуйста как в моем случае можно использовать данный паттерн? Спасибо.

Comment: `private volatile boolean correct;

    public booolean isCorrect(){

       if (!correct){

          synchronezed (this){

           if (!correct){
          computeCorrectess();
}}
         }
       return correct;
      }`

Убираем синхронизацию с метода computeCorrectess()?

Comment: Всё верно у вас. Если `computeCorrectness` больше нигде не планируется использовать и он так и будет инкапсулирован, то синхронизацию можно убрать. Можете поиграться с проверочным кодом из ответа PeterSlusar, дабы проверить что всё в порядке.

Answer (score 4):

Проблема будет с методом  `isCorrect` а если быть совсем точным с синхронизацией метода private synchronized void computeCorrectess()

Все потоки дошедшие до данного метода станут в очередь пройдя логическую развилку:

```
if (!correct) { }
```

и как далее понятно первый вошедший поток изменит состояние флага но очередь потоков уже возможно будет сформирована. 
Проверочный код:

```
public class SomeClass implements Runnable {
    SomeData someData = new SomeData();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SomeClass().threadsGenerator();
    }

    private void threadsGenerator() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            new Thread(this).start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            someData.isCorrect();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class SomeData {
        private boolean correct;
        private boolean computed;

        public SomeData() {
            correct = false;
            computed = false;
        }

        public boolean isCorrect() throws InterruptedException {
            if (!correct) {
                computeCorrectess();
            }
            return correct;
        }

        private synchronized void computeCorrectess() throws InterruptedException {
            System.out.println(correct);
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            correct = true;
        }
    }
}
```

рекомендую к [прочтению](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-5things15/)